# JQuery-UI Datepicker Cannot read property 'replace' of undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a problem with my jquery-ui datepicker. I init the date picker with

```
$( function() {
  $(".datetime").datepicker();
});
```

On load there is no error. But when I focus my form input the console gives me this error

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'replace' of undefined
at i.a.datepicker._showDatepicker (widget.timepicker.min.js?v=5.1.4.00.08:1)
at HTMLInputElement.<anonymous> (widget.timepicker.min.js?v=5.1.4.00.08:1)
at HTMLInputElement.dispatch (jquery-2.2.3.min.js?v=5.1.4.00.08:3)
at HTMLInputElement.r.handle (jquery-2.2.3.min.js?v=5.1.4.00.08:3)
```

Here my HTML

```
<input type="text" id="P2010_VON" name="P2010_VON" required="" aria-required="true" class="text_field apex-item-text datetime hasDatepicker" value="17.07.2018 09:29" size="30" maxlength="">
```

What is the problem?

Comment: i tried the above code its working, can you check on this pen. As i am missing anything https://codepen.io/anon/pen/EpKGjN

Comment: Is it possibel that im using the wrong jquery version?

Comment: can you let me know which version jquery are you using

Comment: I'm use Version 2.3.3

Comment: yeah will check with jquery 2.3.3 and whats the version of datepicker js and css

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please check your versions of scripts. Please see the below code

```js
$( function() {
  $(".datetime").datepicker();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/datepicker/0.6.5/datepicker.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/datepicker/0.6.5/datepicker.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
    <input type="text" id="P2010_VON" name="P2010_VON" required="" aria-required="true" class="text_field apex-item-text datetime hasDatepicker" value="17.07.2018 09:29" size="30" maxlength="">
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that your html is using  jquery ui

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
```